# Proof of isometries and inverses on the plane

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I am taking a course on Intuitive Geometry. I am quite new to intuitive proofs however feel I've done pretty well thus far. Here is my theorem:

**Prove: That every isometry has an inverse.**

$Proof.$

We shall distinguish cases.

**Case 1.**

Let $M,Q$ be points on the plane and let $T$ be a translation such that $T(M) = Q$ and $T'(Q) = M$. We have: $M = T'(T(M)) = T'(Q)$, and $T' \circ T = T \circ T' = I$. We conclude that $T'$ is the inverse.

**Case 2.**

Let $G_x$ be a rotation relative to a point $O$. Let $x$ be in the form $360n + w$ where $n$ is an integer and $w$ is a number such that $0 \le w < 360$. We have: $G_x \circ G_{-x} = G_{-x} \circ G_x = I$. And $G_{-x}$ is the inverse.

**Case 3.**

Let $R$ be a reflection relative to a point $O$ on the plane. Then $R = G_{180}$, and $G_{180} \circ G_{180} = G_{360} = G_{0} = I$. Whence: $R \circ R = I$; $R$ is the inverse.

Suppose now that $R$ is a reflection through a line $L_{PQ}$ and $M$ is a point perpendicular to $L_{PQ}$. Then the case is trivial and $R(R(M)) = M$ and we are done.

I'd like to know if this is solid and if there is a better way. I feel as if perhaps the explicit cases are not necessary (however satisfactory) and there is a more intuitive approach for distance-preserving mappings on the plane.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are general results that every  isometry on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has inverse. It follows from the fact that  every isometry is a composition of an orthogonal linear map and a translation map. Since the latter are isometries and hence their composition. Also their inverse are orthogonal and translation maps respectively. You can refer the book 'Algebra by M Artin'

Comment: Thank you. In terms of just $\mathbb{R}^2$ do you think this is fine or could be improved?